# Denote a ``limiting path'' by $ p := \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{\bigcup_{\ell \geq n} p_\ell}.$ Show that $p \in P$.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, connectedness

Fix $x \neq y \in \Bbb R^n$. Denote by the class of "paths" connecting $x$ and $y$ the collection of sets

$$ P\equiv P(x,y) := \{ p \subset \Bbb R^n: \text{$p$ connected and compact},\ x,y \in p\}.$$
Assume that $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset P(x,y)$ is "uniformly bounded" in the sense that there exist $R > 0$ such that $p_n \subset B(0,R)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Denote a "limiting path" by

$$ p := \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{\bigcup_{\ell \geq n} p_\ell}.$$
Show that $p \in P$.

My try:

Each $\overline{\bigcup_{\ell \geq n} p_\ell}$ is closed and bounded and connected. [As they are subset of $\overline{B(0,R)}$ and $p_l$ has two points $x,y$ in common.] Then
$$ p := \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{\bigcup_{\ell \geq n} p_\ell}.$$ is compact.

I am having trouble to understand why $p$ is connected. In generally for nested connected set, the intersection is not connected. So I am guessing that I have to use compact somehow. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If $p$ is not connected, we can write it as $H\cup K$, where $H$ and $K$ are disjoint, non-empty closed sets. There are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $H\subseteq U$ and $K\subseteq V$. Let $n\in\Bbb N$; the connectedness of $p_n$ implies that $p_n\nsubseteq U\cup V$ (why?), so there is an $x_n\in p_n\setminus(U\cup V)$. The sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is bounded, so it has a convergent subsequence. Consider the limit of that subsequence.

Comment: I have a question. The following is my argument

Comment: If $p$ is not connected, we can write it as $H\cup K$, where $H$ and $K$ are disjoint, non-empty closed sets. Let $n\in\Bbb N$; the connectedness of $p_n$ implies that $p_n\nsubseteq U\cup V$ (why?), so there is an $x_n\in p_n\setminus(H\cup K)$. The sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is bounded, so it has a convergent subsequence. Consider the limit of that subsequence. Suppose the limit is $x$. Then $x \in A_n$ for all $n$ then $x \in p$ but $ x\not \in H\cup K$ a contradiction.

Comment: Why have you introduced $U$ and $V$? What I got is we can start with $H,K$ closed or $U,V$ open; we can also consider something clopen but taking out both is slightly overkill because the topological property of the partitions of $p$ isn't much of a use. E.g we just have two disjoint set whose union is $p$ we will get a contradiction. Because by the compactness of $p$ the limit $x$ has to be in $p$. Isn't it? Otherwise, I am missing something.

Comment: @Ri-Li: What you’re missing is that even if the points $x_n$ are not in $H\cup K$, it’s possible that $x\in H\cup K$. The points $\frac1n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ are not in $\{0\}$, for instance, but their limit is. But $U\cup V$ is open, so if the $x_n$ are not in $U\cup V$, $x$ cannot be in $U\cup V$, either: $U\cup V$ would be an open nbhd of $x$ that contained none of the points $x_n$.